# Vector Calculus identity

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Consider:

$$\iiint\limits_R \left(v\triangle u+\nabla v\nabla u\right)\,dV = \iint\limits_{\partial R} v(\nabla u \cdot n)\,dS$$

How can i prove that for $\triangle u=0$ in $R$ and $u=0$ in $\partial R$, $u$ can be only $0$ ($u = 0$)?

Making the substitutions, we have: $0 = ∇v∇u$

so $∇v$ or $∇u$ is $0$

as $∆u =0$, $∇u$ needs to be zero, as such $u$ should be null to?

Would that be right? I'm having difficulties in wrapping my head around this subject.

Comment: Let $v=u$ and see what happens.

Comment: @JacobA You misunderstand the Laplacian.

Comment: Do $u,v$ map to $\mathbb R$ (multivariate scalar function) or do they map to $\mathbb R^n$ (multivariate vector-valued function) ?

In any case, I think you need to take the scalar product of $\nabla u, \nabla v$ on the RHS:
$$ \iiint_R v \Delta u + \nabla v \color{red} \cdot \nabla u dV$$